# Can you use Azure DevOps with Sitecore Managed Cloud

Tags: azure, best-practices

When implementing [Sitecore Managed Cloud](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/17678/246), what deployment or technical considerations need to be thought about?

As an example: in modern deployments, using Azure DevOps is a viable deployment solution.  This is sometimes mixed with Powershell commands, WebDeploy packages, etc. But to use Azure DevOps, requires having it attached to the Azure subscription.

Does this still work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. However, I think you'll need to either be a recognised Sitecore partner, or use one to set it up for you. The actual Azure DevOps organisation will need to be on a separate (non managed cloud) subscription to the managed cloud subscription, and then the partner can contact Sitecore support and request them to create a [Service Principal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) which you can use in Azure DevOps to connect to the managed cloud subscription.

More info on how access is given is available [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/133931).

Comment: Is there doumentation on Sitecore's site about that request? Are partners supposed to *just know*?

Comment: I've added a link with more info, but in my case it was simply my experience in that I knew I needed a service principal, and sitecore support created it for me (the company I work for is a partner).

Comment: Same for me. I knew I needed an Azure Service Principal. Looping back to your original question about MC, Sitecore manages the access. The ASP as to be created in their AD group, and given access to the subscriptions to be able to deploy. I just created a ticket requesting that they created the ASP and send us the information.